# Не парсится JSON через Python

Tags: python, json, парсер

Всем привет, есть такой файл

```
{
  "rss": {
    "_xmlns:votpusk": "https://www.tourist.ru/news.asp",
    "_version": "2.0",
    "channel": {
      "description": "Африка - Лента туристических новостей портала",
      "lastBuildDate": "Thu, 1 Dec 2016 17:27 +0300 ",
      "items": [
        {
          "guid": "https://www.tourist.ru/news.asp?msg=544347",
          "_id": "544347",
          "pubDate": "Mon, 17 Oct 2016 00:28 +0300",
          "description": "texttexttext",
          "link": "texttext",
          "title": "text"
        },
        {
          "guid": "https://www.tourist.ru/news.asp?msg=544347",
          "_id": "544347",
          "pubDate": "Mon, 17 Oct 2016 00:28 +0300",
          "description": "texttexttext",
          "link": "texttext",
          "title": "text"
        },и так, далее...
```

Хочу запарсить вот так через Python

```
import json

def ParsJSON(path):
    with open(path) as filejson:
        _result = json.load(filejson)
    return _result

AllNews = ParsJSON("newsafr.json")
```

Но выходит ошибка на  json.load(filejson)

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 509: character maps to <undefined>
```

В питоне новичек, в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать кодировку файла

```
with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as filejson:
```

P.S. И почитайте [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), ваш код его нарушает.

Comment: все получилось спс open(path, encoding='utf-8-sig')

Comment: @Kiril [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).